# Question on divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the expressions $2x+3y$ and $9x+5y$ are divisible by $17$ for the same set of integral values $x$ and $y$.

I took arbitrary values of $x$ and $y$ as $l$ and $m$ respectively, after which I wrote $2l+3m= 17k$.
Then i wrote $9x+5y$ as $2x+3y+(7x+2m)$.
But I cannot figure out how to make $7l+2m=17p$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Eliminate $x$ or $y$
$9(2x+3y)-2(9x+5y)=?$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can control the congruences $$ 9x+5y\equiv 0 \pmod {17}$$ and $$ 2x+3y\equiv0\pmod {17}$$ when $x =0,1,2...16$ and control of values of $y$ coincide